# Table creation for cross section line using QGIS

Tags: qgis, table, cross-section

When I export a 2D .dxf line with the profile tool in QGIS 3.28.5, it also creates some empty layers in the dxf. Dimensions, table background, table content, table grid and viewports.

Is there a way to export the profile line along with an information table, such as some lisp does in a CAD environment?